# Generating a Provable List of Sets of Scenarios

Tags: state, boolean-logic

I'm asking this with full knowledge that this idea is probably well covered in a subject unfamiliar to me. Suppose you're writing a small piece of code that takes an input of an arbitrary number of variables. Those variables can have several states, namely:

1. Correct Data
2. Incorrect Data (outside range, improper formatting, whatever)
3. Unknown (Null)

So if we have 3 input variables, and 3 states per those variables, we end up with 27 possible scenarios. Suppose I have to do some logic based on the state of certain variables, or the combination of states (AND, NAND, OR, etc). Can I easily structure a program in such a way that I provably cover all scenarios without an absolute mess of if/else style logic? The first thing that came to mind was statemachines, but after looking at them for a bit I'm not entirely convinced it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There will be if style logic, but you can use [karnaugh maps](http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/elessonshtml/Logic/Logic3.html) to make it much cleaner and be sure that you've covered every possibility. What you do, is you make a grid showing every possible combination of states. Then, mark each state in a different way depending on the way you want to react to it. The goal of this is to group states. Then, you can easily see if your groups of states are logically "close together," and if so, you can simplify your control logic. A quick search for karnaugh maps will bring up [explanations](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/minimisation/karnaugh.html) that will be much easier to follow thanks to pictures, but the idea is to use the grid to see which variables are irrelevant to a group of states, and optimize them out of the logic.